# Save file for gta 5

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-v

I got on my game today but it started a new game. It was a whole new file, now I don't know how to change to my old save file please help. How do you do that?

Answer (score -2):

I Know this Answer isn't right because it's an Solution for PC. But first I didn't saw the XBoX tag. And if you google this question, some desperate PC player, with the same Problem will be lead here and hopefully find his answer.

Right click on the GTA V Folder (C:\Users\username\Documents\Rockstar Games\GTA V) select "Properties" and then the tab "Previous Version" and select one Date, which was before you saved your new game. But be aware, the new save file will be overwritten. Make a backup copy, if you want to keep them.

the Place of Save files:
C:\Users\username\Documents\Rockstar Games\GTA V\ and drill down until you see the SGTA and PGTA files. These are the save files.

this works only if you have restore points active, which are usually enabled for the Documents folder.

Comment: I Think the XBOX 360 don't have a C:\ HDD ;) (when the tag is right)

Comment: ohh sry. Dind't see it was XBoX

Comment: And this **downvote isn't justifiable**, because the Question wasn't specifc enough. The Tag is not enough! And it's actually right! My Opinion...